# How to make lamp accessible via raspberry pi access point

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I made lamp server on raspberry pi 3. I can access it if I type rp static ip address in web browser, or localhost or 127.0.0.1.

I also made standalone access point with static ip disconnected from internet to which I can connect i.e. with mobile phone.

However, I don't know what I have to do in order to access the webpage from mobile phone. If I type above mentioned addresses in webpage it gives me error that connection is refused.

Comment: When you connect from mobile phone, go into `Settings`->`WiFi` and see the router or default gateway IP address and use that to mean the Raspberry Pi's IP address.

Comment: When I looked at raspberry pi destinatiom was set to 192.168.4.0 and gateway to 0.0.0.0. I assumed that there could be problem, but please be aware that RP is, and should be disconnected from internet and should work as standalone network access point